# log4j - filtering by class instead of level

Tags: log4j

In my app, I need to download 3 different artifacts from a remote ftp server.  After I download each artifact, I validate the artifacts.  And, if there are any validation errors, I need to log them aka

validation errors with Artifact A => A.log

validation errors with Artifact B => B.log

validation errors with Artifact C => C.log

My log4j.properties looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, rollingfile
log4j.logger.artifactALogger=INFO, AppenderA
log4j.logger.artifactBLogger=INFO, AppenderB
log4j.logger.artifactCLogger=INFO, AppenderC

log4j.appender.AppenderA.File=A.log
log4j.appender.AppenderA.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.AppenderA.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.AppenderA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AppenderA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.AppenderB.File=B.log
log4j.appender.AppenderB.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.AppenderB.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.AppenderB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AppenderB.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.AppenderC.File=C.log
log4j.appender.AppenderC.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.AppenderC.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.AppenderC.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AppenderC.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

As you can see, I have 1 appender per logger and the configuration for each appender is exactly the same (except for the name of the log file)...alot of duplication!  Down the line, if I end up with more artifacts to download, I would need to declare another logger and another appender for each artifact.  Something just doesn't seem right to me doing it this way.  Maybe, I'm just not using log4j the way it was designed to be used?  I'm currently filtering log output by class rather than by log level.  Should I be using a different logging API that is more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom logger for log4j for this purpose. We had a similar requirement once and ended up creating a custom logger.

Comment: So, other than creating a custom logger, I'm kinda stuck doing it the way I'm currently doing it?  Creating a custom logger seems kinda excessive...

Comment: I am afraid so. But, custom logger is not as painful as it seems and could be helpful when you actually need tons of these classifications